# Cannot open the terminal via Ctrl + Alt + t

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

Since I have booted my pc today with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS I have experienced some issues.

First, my settings have disappeared, meaning the app and the icon on the top right where "wired connection" is. Then I tried fixing it which worked. However in addition to that I could not open the terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> as well as with <kbd>super key</kbd> and then searching and clicking it. The only way I was able to open the terminal was by going into a file and then right click and "open in terminal" (It did not work when trying on the desktop).

I have checked the shortcut in the settings and that is not the problem. I have also tried to purge and re-install gnome-terminal. Did not work either and there has been the following errors:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
 update-notifier
 ubuntu-desktop
 ubuntu-desktop-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Something that might be helpful is that when searching for the terminal and clicking on it on the top left at "Activities" there is "terminal" but hovering over it with the cursor shows that it just loads. However it does not open. It might be correlated to some changes I did when trying to install the new python 3.11.2 version since it cannot be updated as easily on Ubuntu.

Comment: Related: [Suddenly Unable to Launch Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158835/suddenly-unable-to-launch-terminal)

Comment: You totally and completly killed the OS when you changed the version of Python. Time for a re install.

Comment: Ubuntu relies on the version of python it ships with, the exact version. Any change to this causes many if not all features to not work. The terminal is one of the things that uses python.

Comment: @David Ok, I understand. But how am I able to install python 3.11.2? Because I knew on should not meddle with the python version I tried following the instructions here: https://hackersandslackers.com/multiple-python-versions-ubuntu-20-04/   Weren't they safe to use or did I make a mistake?

Comment: You do not replace the default you do some research and see there is a way to have more then one version of python on the machine and not replace the default. BTW No current version of Ubuntu runs the 3.11 version of Python.

Comment: I took a quick look and that site seems fine you must have messed up the instructions.

Comment: Yeah, I added the newest version as an alternative and switched to it which solved the problem. But that is pretty weird that one has to have multiple versions switch between them. Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: You can have multiple python versions installed; you access then using `python3.8` to access 3.8 for example, but `python` or `python3` should always run the *default* version your system came with, esp. on Desktop installs if you want the Ubuntu utilities/apps to run correctly.

Comment: @Karel It already has been solved. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: How did you solve it? If your reply is too long for a comment could you post a link?

Comment: I followed the instructions here: https://hackersandslackers.com/multiple-python-versions-ubuntu-20-04/   It tells you to install newer python versions as alternatives and switch between them. The problem I had only occured when being on the newer python version. However after switching eberything worked fine again.